# Probability of choosing the correct option

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find a proof of that theorem that says that if there is a *correct* candidate in an election and if voters are slightly better than random guessing at identifying and voting for this candidate, i.e. they have slightly better than uniform probability of choosing him, then independent and uncorrelated voting will elect this candidate with probability close to $1$ given a large enough number of voters.

Is this *central limit theorem*? How does one prove it?

---

***Formalizing:***

Consider a set of $N$ balls in a box which are not completely spherical but have some imperfections,

$B_{1},B_{2},\cdots,B_{N}$.

A person (or system) is asked to choose the most spherical of all balls, say $B_{0}$ from the box. Suppose this person has a probability of choosing the correct ball which is just slightly better than $1/N$. Show that if $M\rightarrow\infty$ persons try their chance and results are averaged, the correct ball will be chosen with probability close to $1$.

Comment: Presumably you are saying at the end that the probability the more likely ball will be chosen more often than each of the others tends to $1$ as the number of trials increases.

Comment: It is (weak) law of large numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it follows from the central limit theorem specialized to the binomial distribution (aka the de Moivre - Laplace theorem). Assuming each chooser makes the 'correct' choice with probability $p$, where $p>1/N$, and that the choices are independent, then after $M$ people make their try the number $X$ of choices that are correct
has binomial ($M$, $p$) distribution. The fraction of choices that are correct is $X/M$, and the probability that this fraction exceeds $1/N$ is
$$P(X/M> 1/N)=P(X> M/N)=P\left({X-Mp\over\sqrt{Mp(1-p)}}> {M/N-Mp\over\sqrt{Mp(1-p)}}\right)$$
As $M\to\infty$ the variable ${X-Mp\over\sqrt{Mp(1-p)}}$ approaches a standard normal variable (by the central limit theorem), while the quantity ${M/N-Mp\over\sqrt{Mp(1-p)}}$ tends to $-\infty$ (for any $p$ such that $\frac1N-p<0$). So the probability tends to 1 that the 'correct' choice is made more frequently than 'expected' when guessing at random.

Comment: Cool. Should had that the approximation is good for $Mp>5$ and $M(1-p)>5$.